# Streaming objects to a subprocess

Tags: java, python, scala

I want to stream n objects to a subprocess, each "object" is a string followed by a newline. The obvious thing is use a temporary file as we can write (on parent process) and read (on child process) **one line** onto memory. But I want to avoid the overhead of writing a temporary file by streaming each object to memory. I used `Popen` with commandline argument to filename and `wait()` to track subprocess.

What is a better way?

Parent process is in python and child in scala, and we run it in Ubuntu 12.04+ , hence I want solutions that take advantage of these.

Comment: Where's the java in this?

Comment: I can use solutions available to Java as Scala runs on JVM

Comment: why write on files? you can put objects on ObjectStream, and pass that stream directly to subprocess.

Comment: When you create a sub-process you have a way of obtaining the file descriptor referencing the *stdin* stream for that new process.

Comment: please give me an example of using pipes

Comment: Parent process writes to stdout. Child process reads from stdin. From the command line run `parent | child`. Another option is using named pipes instead of a file (`man mkpipe`).